# Node crypto decryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am trying to decode password using crypto.js based on different algorithms. I am able to encode the string but failed to decode it using following code.

`crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ctr', password)`

Error::

```
    crypto.js:216
  this._handle.init(cipher, toBuf(password));

TypeError: Key must be a buffer
    at new Decipher (crypto.js:216:16)
    at Object.Decipher (crypto.js:213:12)
```

Comment: First thing - it's deprecated https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options

Comment: Second thing - CTR uses a nonce, and you aren't providing one.

Comment: Sorry guys, my mistake. Someone hard coded password in environment variable. Fortunately i was able to locate and remove it. This is a very old code. I just jumped in to fix it.